# How to filter MongoDB data based on time interval

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I have a mongo collection where document is like  below

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("000000006265b7810385678")
  "created_at": 2022-09-06T13:05:58.165+00:00
  "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      45.55797,
      9.930558
    ]
  }
  "location_name": "Some random location"
  "phone_number": "123456",
  "remark": "Success",
  "time_recorded": "21:37:08 20-09-2022",
  "updated_at":2022-09-06T13:05:58.165+00:00
}

{
  "_id": ObjectId("000000006265b7810385678")
  "created_at": 2022-09-06T13:05:58.165+00:00
  "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      45.55797,
      9.930558
    ]
  }
  "location_name": "Some random location"
  "phone_number": "123456",
  "remark": "Success",
  "time_recorded": "21:37:08 20-09-2022",
  "updated_at":2022-09-06T13:20:58.165+00:00
}

{
  "_id": ObjectId("000000006265b7810385678")
  "created_at": 2022-09-06T13:05:58.165+00:00
  "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      45.55797,
      9.930558
    ]
  }
  "location_name": "Some random location"
  "phone_number": "123456",
  "remark": "Success",
  "time_recorded": "21:37:08 20-09-2022",
  "updated_at":2022-09-06T13:35:58.165+00:00
}
```

Each document is created on an interval of 15 min.
My requirement is to find all documents with a particular phone number, but the data which is updated is on interval of 30 min (and this 30 min is a variable like 1 hour also.)
like if I query for phone number 123456 for 30 min interval then I will get 2 records only if I take above example. (2 records of timestamp 2022-09-06T13:05:58.165+00:00,2022-09-06T13:35:58.165+00:00).

How can I write mongodb query to achieve that.
and in output I want all the fields which is present in one document as it is to display.

like here I want output like that.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("000000006265b7810385678")
  "created_at": 2022-09-06T13:05:58.165+00:00
  "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      45.55797,
      9.930558
    ]
  }
  "location_name": "Some random location"
  "phone_number": "123456",
  "remark": "Success",
  "time_recorded": "21:37:08 20-09-2022",
  "updated_at":2022-09-06T13:05:58.165+00:00
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("000000006265b7810385678")
  "created_at": 2022-09-06T13:05:58.165+00:00
  "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      45.55797,
      9.930558
    ]
  }
  "location_name": "Some random location"
  "phone_number": "123456",
  "remark": "Success",
  "time_recorded": "21:37:08 20-09-2022",
  "updated_at":2022-09-06T13:35:58.165+00:00
}
```

please help me, Tried aggregate, but failed to write query as I am new in mongodb

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("000000006265b7810385678")
  "created_at": 2022-09-06T13:05:58.165+00:00
  "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      45.55797,
      9.930558
    ]
  }
  "location_name": "Some random location"
  "phone_number": "123456",
  "remark": "Success",
  "time_recorded": "21:37:08 20-09-2022",
  "updated_at":2022-09-06T13:05:58.165+00:00
}

{
  "_id": ObjectId("000000006265b7810385678")
  "created_at": 2022-09-06T13:05:58.165+00:00
  "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      45.55797,
      9.930558
    ]
  }
  "location_name": "Some random location"
  "phone_number": "123456",
  "remark": "Success",
  "time_recorded": "21:37:08 20-09-2022",
  "updated_at":2022-09-06T13:35:58.165+00:00
}
```

I tried below query

```
db.CollectionName.aggregate([
  {"$group": {
    "_id": "$updated_at",
      overallTime: { 
        $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H", date: "$updated_at" } 
      },
      interval: {$divide: [{ $minute: "$updated_at" }, 30 ]},
  }},
])
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried aggregate function and group on updated_at, but did not sure how to use that to get my expected output.

Comment: Please show us your query. Edit the question for that information.